How do you iterate through raster bands using model designer in QGIS?
I am processing atmospheric data and I need to convert my raster input into polygons so I can find the intersection values between my pixels and other polygon features. I used the Raster Pixels to Polygons algorithm as a part of my process. Each input file has multiple bands representing different time periods.
I have built a model that successfully processes my files, but I have to manually select the bands and change the output name each time. Is there a way to automatically iterate through the bands present in my raster-turned polygon input and adjust the output name for each iteration?

If my answer worked: What should I do when someone answers my question?

I'm still learning how to use the model designer. Your answer has helped, but it brought up a few more questions that I'm still working through. Parts of your answer are making more sense as I figure things out. I will mark it answered or add some follow-up questions here shortly.

You can execute the model in Batch mode.
I've created a model with:

A number parameter (for the band number)
Raster layer parameter
Vector layer parameter


Run - Run as batch process. Add rows for each band, using Fill down or calculate by expression.
Calculate the output parameter with Calculate by Expression, using the band parameter as input. Replace @number_parameter with the name of your parameter, and the gpkg path and table name
format('ogr:dbname=/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/test.gpkg table=output_band_%1 (geom)', @number_parameter)


